# While reinstalling OS in MacBook Pro, qwerty keyboard option in not coming

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I had erased the disk data and reinstalled OS in MacBook Pro.
I selected regions like India , US and input sources like ABC (which was shown as default) and also US , British etc.
In none of the cases i could see the qwerty English keyboard working. For example if I'm pressing 'p' in apple id setup or account creation options it's coming as pi in Greek letters.
I tried to change many input sources but none seems to work.
Kindly help.

Comment: Test the first few letters, top left, with it set to English - just `qwerty` is enough - & let us know exactly what is typed. My guess would be `œ∑´®†¥` which would imply your Option key is stuck down.

Comment: Try an external keyboard.